# DatabaseError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query in python

Tags: html, sql-server, python-2.7, pandas, flask

I am trying to return a date selected from date picker in to my sql query in my python code. I also tried using `encode(utf-8)` to remove the unicode string but still, I am getting the error.

I am new to python. Can anyone please help me figure out how to solve this problem? I am using python flask to create the webpage

```
if request.method=='POST':
        dateval2 = request.form['datepick']
        dateval = dateval2.encode('utf-8')
    result = ("SELECT * FROM OE_TAT where convert(date,Time_IST)='?'",dateval
    df = pd.read_sql_query(result,connection)`
```

**Error**:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '("SELECT * FROM OE_TAT where convert(date,Time_IST)='?'", '2015-06-01')': The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

Comment: In which format comes the date from the date picker?

Comment: Format : "yy-mm-dd" same as my sql server database format

Comment: This is the exact error i am getting : pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '("SELECT * FROM OE_TAT where convert(date,Time_IST)='?'", '2015-06-02')': The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.

Comment: You are providing a tuple to [`read_sql_query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html), while the first argument (the query) has to be a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are providing a tuple to [`read_sql_query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html), while the first argument (the query) has to be a string. That's why it gives the error "The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query".

You can pass the parameter like this:

```
result = "SELECT * FROM OE_TAT where convert(date,Time_IST)=?"
df = pd.read_sql_query(result, connection, params=(dateval,))
```

Note that the use of `?` depends on the driver you are using (there are different ways to specify parameters, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). It is possible you will have to use `%s` instead of `?`.

You could also format the string in beforehand, like `result = "SELECT * FROM OE_TAT where convert(date,Time_IST)={0}".format(dateval)`, however, this is not recommended, see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)